# Getting sAMAccountName

Tags: perl, winapi, active-directory, ldap

Sorry for the simple (newbie) question - but I have a Perl script using WIN32API::NET.

I have a list of user account cn= values.

Is there a WIN32API::NET command that will give me the sAMAccountName for a cn= ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any issues using net::ldap instead?

Perhaps you could take a look at some examples here:

http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::LDAP::Examples

Just plug in the attributes you have and the attributes you need in the relevant locations.

Comment: Yes Damien I was able to use net::ldap to accomplish this. Thanks for your help.